# What does this tutorial mean? Using create-react-native-app with Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, expo

I am trying to use Navigator in React Native Project with Expo.
Actually there are two major navigator in react native, react-native-router-flux and react-native-navigation.

However, some documents mentioning react-native-router-flux say RNRF is not used with Expo because Expo doesn't follow this.

But please look at this Link about RNRF and Expo.
I don't know why this document can uses react-native-create-app command and Expo SDK. I think basically if we would like to use Expo in RN app, we have to use expo start command.

I didn't understand what is happening to this tutorial...

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-make-a-simple-twitter-clone-with-react-native-4b6c45940583

So, could you explain this, please.

Below are my questions.

1. Can we use Expo thorough [react-native-create-app]?
2. Can react-native-router-flux be used with Expo?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create react native app shouldn't be used anymore. See here...
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

> Note: This repository has been archived and the issue tracker for Create React Native App has moved to: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues

Instead, use [Expo CLI](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/installation)

Since RNRF is a javascript only router, you should be able to use it no problem.